# PHP Widget System... Best way to store widget content?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a widget management system similar to that of WordPress.  I have several different types of widgets that I want to offer including category article feed, new members, recent or upcoming events, statistics, content, etc.

My issue is that each of these widget types will have different settings or options.  For example, the category article feed will have options like result limit, display method (bootstrap thumbnail or media). The stats widget would have the ability to enable which stats to show. The content widget would only have an option for what content to display.

If it's possible, then I don't want to have separate MySQL tables for each of these different types of widgets.

What would be the best way to store this information?